# '/lib/modules/4.9.8-1-ARCH' is not a valid kernel module directory

Tags: arch-linux, mkinitcpio

I am attempting to repair and upgrade an Arch Linux system. I boot off of a Live USB which is a newer version than the original install. Then I mount the sda and chroot to its mount point. When I run `mkinitcpio -p linux`, I get the error from the title:

```
'/lib/modules/4.9.8-1-ARCH' is not a valid kernel module directory
```

`lib/modules/` has 4.13.3-1-ARCH. How do I tell `mkinitcpio` to use this directory instead?

Comment: From the chroot, what is the output of `uname -r && pacman -Q linux`?

Comment: @jasonwryan `4.12.8-2-ARCH` and `linux 4.13.3-1`

Comment: So `/boot` wasn't mounted when you upgraded your kernel. Make sure it is, re-run the kernel upgrade and you should be good.

Comment: @jasonwryan Thanks. Some digging finally lead me to the same conclusion. I believe I am back in business.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is that I forgot to mount my boot partition to `/boot` when I upgraded my entire system, including the Linux kernel. After dealing with some issues with `pacman` and PGP keys, I finally ran `pacman -S filesystem linux` and I am able to boot off of my HDD. (I'm not sure if `filesystem` was required to fix this problem, but it was referenced in other sources.)

Comment: I had this problem with Arch Linux 4.14.3-1-ARCH. Your solution worked. I was not able to boot before, then I reinstalled `filesystem linux` and everything worked.

Comment: And now you‘ll likely need `linux-headers` too.

Answer (score 7):

Just fyi, I had a similar issue and fixed it with just `pacman -S linux`. I don't think filesystem was needed.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and reinstalling with `pacman -S linux` did not help. In fact the error appeared when updating `linux-aarch64` in the first place because that triggers the post-transaction hook for `mkinitcpio`!

The problem in my case was that `/etc/mkinitcpio.d/linux-aarch64.preset` was not replaced by the update but a `.pacnew` file was installed. So the preset still pointed to the old modules directory. Moving the new preset in place fixed it:

```
# mv /etc/mkinitcpio.d/linux-aarch64.preset{.pacnew,}
# pacman -S linux-aarch64
```