# No mkinitcpio preset present

Tags: arch-linux, initramfs, pacman, mkinitcpio

My laptop lost battery during an update, so the linux kernel got truncated. After `arch-chroot`ing into it and reinstalling `linux`, it's OK, but `/boot/initramfs-linux.img` (and the fallback) are empty. Also, `/etc/mkinitcpio.d/linux.preset` is empty. How can I fix this, and how can I generate a preset?

`ls /etc/mkinitcpio.d/` returns nothing

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Regenerate a new `initramfs-linux.img` accordingly to the [archlinux wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Mkinitcpio):

```
mkinitcpio -c /etc/mkinitcpio.conf -g /boot/initramfs-linux.img -k 5.5.7-arch1-1
```

use `ls /usr/lib/modules` to get the available kernel.

Comment: I just get `/usr/sbin/mkinitcpio: line 265: /etc/mkinitcpio.d/linux.preset: No such file or directory
==> ERROR: Failed to load preset: /etc/mkinitcpio.d/linux.preset'` on the second command

Comment: Yes, it's installed and I've reinstalled it

Comment: @RHarrington could you add the `ls /etc/mkinitcpio.d/`

Comment: @RHarrington See my edit please.

Comment: I'm chrooted in, so I get `==> ERROR: '/lib/modules/5.1.0-050100-generic' is not a valid kernel module directory
` because of my host's kernel. How can I fix this?

Comment: @RHarrington see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/395402/lib-modules-4-9-8-1-arch-is-not-a-valid-kernel-module-directory

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105171/discussion-between-r-harrington-and-gad3r).

Comment: Down-voted as this is not a permanent fix. You'll have to do this manually every time you upgrade linux. The other answer is a permanent fix.

Comment: @GaryvanderMerwe downvote is used for the wrong answer, not for the accepted answer.

Answer (score 10):

Had this recently. My [solution](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1894916#p1894916) was to chroot into the system from an Arch live system. Delete the empty `linux.preset` in `/etc/mkinitcpio.d/` and then run `pacman -S linux`.

This regenerated the `linux.preset` and the `initramfs` was rebuild. After that Arch booted as usual.

Comment: it is worked! correct

Comment: This is a better answer because it fixes the problem permanently

Comment: Confirming this in 2024, I prefer this streamlined approach over forced generation.